# Checking if given preorder traversal is valid BST

Tags: algorithm

I was writing code to check from preorder traversal if it is a valid BST. 
e.g preorder traversal `1,2,4,3,5`  is valid BST while `1,3,4,2` is not

I built whole tree from that preorder sequence and then checked if that tree is a valid BST. This is `O(N)` solutions with respect to both space and time complexity.

Does anybody have good approach than this? I have intuition that we can do this in O(1) extra space.

Comment: How do you uniquely construct a Tree only with preorder ?

Comment: "I have intuition that we can do this in O(1) extra space." Why?

Comment: My solution with O(1) space - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63698918/1465553

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Checking whether a permutation of 1..n is a preorder of a valid BST (that BST, if it exists, is unique; imreal's answer is not a counterexample because the second reconstruction is not sorted) is equivalent to testing whether that permutation is stack-sortable, i.e., avoids the 231-pattern. I can't seem to find any linear-time constant-space algorithm under any of these names, which would tend to suggest given the amount of attention that this problem has attracted that no one knows of a constant extra space solution.

If you're willing to assume a read/write input that can be destroyed, then there's a linear-time algorithm that uses constant extra space. It's not necessary to reconstruct the tree separately and then test it. Here's some Python to that effect.

```py
def isbstpreorder(iterable):
    lowerbound = None
    stack = []
    for x in iterable:
        if lowerbound is not None and x < lowerbound: return False
        while stack and stack[-1] < x: lowerbound = stack.pop()
        stack.append(x)
    return True
```

To eliminate the separate storage for the stack, store it in a prefix of the input list.

Comment: @David Eisenstat How stack-sortable condition suffices that the preorder sequence is valid for a BST?

Comment: @Prashant The preorder traversal looks like <root><preorder of left subtree><right subtree>. Necessity follows by case analysis: the root cannot be involved in a hypothetical violation, since all elements less than the root precede all greater; the 2 cannot belong to the left subtree with the 1 belonging to the right subtree, by the same logic; thus the hypothetical violation is local to one subtree, and we dispatch this case with an inductive hypothesis. Sufficiency is a similar proof; use the 231 condition with 2 being the root to show that the left subtree appears before the right; induct.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to check if the input array can be divided into two sub arrays representing the left and the right sub tree. Obviously, this has to be done recursively.

Here's some tested Java code to illustrate the same:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PreOrderBSTCheck {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ipStr = "1 4 2 3";
        String[] ipArr = ipStr.split(" ");

        int[] intArr = new int[ipArr.length];
        List<Integer> listArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < ipArr.length ; i++)
        {
            intArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(ipArr[i]);
            listArr.add(intArr[i]);
        }
        //System.out.println("List size: "+listArr.size());
        if(checkTree(listArr))
            System.out.println("Valid");
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid");
    }

    public static boolean checkTree(List<Integer> arr)
    {
        if(arr.size() == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Integer root = arr.get(0);
        int idx = 1;

        //adding left subtree nodes
        while(arr.get(idx) < root)
        {
            left.add(arr.get(idx++));

            if(idx >= arr.size())
                break;
        }

        //adding right subtree nodes
        if(! (idx >= arr.size()))
            while(arr.get(idx) > root)
            {
                right.add(arr.get(idx++));

                if(idx >= arr.size())
                    break;
            }

        if(left.size() + right.size() == arr.size() - 1)
        {
            if(left.size()==0)
            {
                return true && checkTree(right);
            }
            else if(right.size() == 0)
            {
                return true && checkTree(left);
            }
            else
            {
                return checkTree(left) && checkTree(right);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You can avoid creating list for each subtree in each recursive. That is unnecessary space overhead, which can simply be avoid by passing the index of original list.

Answer (score 1):

```
isBST(vector<int> &A) {
    int a=0,b=1,c=2;

    if(A.size() <= 2)
    return 1;

    while(c < A.size())
    {
        if(A[a] < A[b] && A[b] > A[c] && A[c] < A[a])
            return 0;
        a++; b++; c++;
    }
    return 1;
}


    8
  7   9   output preorder 8 7 9

    7
     8
      9   output preorder 7 8 9
    
    7
      9
     8    output preorder 7 9 8

    9
  7
   8      output preorder 9 7 8

    9
   8
  7       out put preorder 9 8 7
```

**BUT FOR 897 Its impossible to build BST**

Comment: it fails for the case {2, 4 ,3} we can make a bst but your solution will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int lower=-1; 
for(long int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(lower>-1 && pre[i] < lower)
            {
                lower=-2;
                break;
            }
            while(!isempty(s) && top(s)<pre[i])
            {
                lower =top(s);
                pop(s);
            }
            push(s,pre[i]);
        }
        if(lower==-2)
        {
            cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
           cout<<"Valid BST"<<endl;
        }
```

This algo will work for any kind of sorted input, not just 1 to n. And it takes O(1) extra space, ie,only the variable 'lower'. If you try to solve this problem using pen and paper, you'll have to keep track of a variable, the one for which you check that  no newly occurring value should be less than this value. Lower acts as that marker for which you check that no new value is lower than 'lower'. And you keep updating 'lower' as soon as you get a higher value.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we can consider here that for preorder traversal array, if at any point on right side of array we find greater element than current element and if any element after that is smaller element, we should consider that BST is not possible from that very preorder traversal given.

e.g: arr[] = {40,30,35,20,80,100} not possible to build valid BST.

Explanation:

Here when we start building the tree 40 becomes the root of the BST,
Now as we proceed 30 goes in left subtree and now we find next greater of 30 which is 35, as we know for any lower or smaller element to be in the left subtree of 30 should must have been between 30 and its next greater i.e 35 here. So, as we traverse forward we find 20 which can't fit in left of 30 as it is after the next greater element and certainly not as child of 35 as it will violate the BST property (i.e any right subtree element must have greater value always in comparison to root). Thus,valid BST can't be made.

Now, to solve this we can use stack as we use it to find the next greater element in an array [Code for next greater element](https://github.com/lucifercr07/Stack/blob/master/nextLargerElement.cpp). Here we have to just ensure after having the next greater no element comes smaller than that after.

In the code we initially take root as INT_MIN lowest possible value,
If the root is anytime lower than current element we return false.
While the current element is greater than the element at the top of stack we pop it and set root as the popped element.
And we push the current element into the stack for further comparison.

```
bool check(int *arr, int n)
{
stack<int> s;
int root=INT_MIN;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    if(arr[i]<root)
        return false;

    while(!s.empty() && arr[i]>s.top())
    {
        root=s.top();
        s.pop();
    }

    s.push(arr[i]);
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool IsBST(List<int> array)
    {       
        var s = new Stack<int>();
        int root = 0;
        
        foreach(var el in array)
        {
            if(el < root)
                return false;
            
            while(s.Count != 0 && el > s.Peek())
            {
                root = s.Peek();
                s.Pop();
            }
            
            s.Push(el);
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without using extra space or container like `stack`:**

Divide the input array into this form `[root] - [left-subtree] - [right-subtree]` and then validate each subtree recursively.

```
public boolean isValidPreorder(int[] A) {
    return util(A, 0, A.length-1);
}
public boolean isValidPreorderUtil(int[] A, int x, int y){
    if (x >= y) return true;
    for (int i = x+1; i <= y; i++){
        if (A[x] < A[i]) {
            for (int k = i+1; k <=y; k++){
                if (A[k] < A[x]) return 0;
            }
            return util(A, x+1, i-1) & util(A, i, y); // both left and right subtree
        }    
    }
    return util(A, x+1, y); // left subtree only
}
```

Comment: This solution is not stack free, the call stack is being used implicitly and space complexity is O(h) in avg. case and O(n) is worst case. Moreover the time complexity is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [Valid BST from Preorder](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/valid-bst-from-preorder/).

My accepted solution int C++ is:

```
int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A) {
    set<int> s;
    for(auto&I: A)
        s.insert(I);
    if(s.size() != A.size())
        return 0;
    int minVal = INT_MIN;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
        if(A[i] <= minVal)
            return 0;
        if(i > 0 && A[i] > A[i-1])
            minVal = A[i-1];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here, function solve takes preorder as vector A. I used set to check for distinct entries and maintained a minVal variable the effectively works as a replacement for stack. Hence my solution takes O(1) extra space and has O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in O(n) time and O(n) auxiliary space complexity (for recursion stack). Root node of the whole tree will be at index 0 in the preorder array. In preorder, every node is followed by set of left subtree element and then the set of right subtree elements. For every node the right subtree will be rooted at the next higher array value from that node. So the basic idea is to recursively divide the preorder array into left and right subtree with the valid range of node values.

```
public class IsBstPossibleFromPreorder {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] preorder = {40, 30, 35, 20, 80};//{6,3,0,5,4,8,7,9};//{3,2,5,1,7};
        System.out.println(isBstPossible(preorder, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, preorder.length-1));
    }

    /*
    li is root of current subtree
    ri is the index of the last element in the current subtree
    min, max range for the elements of current subtree
     */
    private static boolean isBstPossible(int[] preorder, int min, int max, int li, int ri){
        if (li==ri && preorder[li]>min && preorder[li]<max){ // if single node subtree...
            return true;
        }
        if (preorder[li]<=min || preorder[li]>=max ){ // if node value out of range
            return false;
        }
        int lsi = preorder[li+1]<preorder[li]?li+1:-1; // left subtree root index (-1 if no left subtree exits for node li)
        int rsi = findNextHigherElementIndex(preorder, li, ri); // right subtree root index (-1 if no right subtree exists for node li)

        boolean isLeftValid = (lsi==-1 || isBstPossible(preorder, min, preorder[li], lsi, rsi-1>lsi?rsi-1:lsi));
        boolean isRightValid =  (rsi==-1 || isBstPossible(preorder, preorder[li], max, rsi, ri));
        return isLeftValid && isRightValid;
    }

    private static int findNextHigherElementIndex(int[] preorder, int li, int ri){
        int x = -1; // -1 if no higher element on right side of li
        for (int i = li+1; i <= ri ; i++) {
            if (preorder[i]>preorder[li]){
                x = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible to uniquely construct a binary tree from a preorder traversal alone, so it is impossible to verify if it is a BST.

For example, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5 can make:

```
    4
  /   \
 2     6
  \   /
  3   5
```

which is a BST and also:

```
4
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      6
       \
        5
```

which is not.

Comment: How does the second example show the non-uniqueness of binary search tree reconstruction?

Comment: Second one is not BST

Comment: @DavidEisenstat both trees produce the same preorder sequence, but they are clearly different trees.

Comment: @imreal We are talking about BST here.

Comment: @VallabhPatade if you can have one tree that is BST and one that isn't, and both generate the same preorder, doesn't that fact prove that it is not possible to use preorder only to verify BST validity?

Comment: @imreal I think all the OP is asking is to show that a given preorder sequence can be associated with a BST.  What you've shown is that a preorder sequence that can be associated with a BST can also be associated with something that is not a BST.  That's not the question though.  The question is to determine when a given sequence can't be associated with a BST at all.

Comment: The second tree is not a BST

Comment: @PunK_l_RuLz That is exactly what I wrote

Comment: The question is that we are given a preorder traversal and we need to check that if that preorder traversal can form a BST and your second diagram is not a BST even if the preorder traversal is the same