# Javascript equivalent code for pre-order traversal check

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how we can write pre-order traversal code written in Java for Javascript?

To start, I am practising this question on geeksforgeeks:

[Check if a given array can represent Preorder Traversal of Binary Search Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-given-array-can-represent-preorder-traversal-of-binary-search-tree/)

For that they wrote this algo

```
1) Create an empty stack.
2) Initialize root as INT_MIN.
3) Do following for every element pre[i]
     a) If pre[i] is smaller than current root, return false.
     b) Keep removing elements from stack while pre[i] is greater
        then stack top. Make the last removed item as new root (to
        be compared next).
        At this point, pre[i] is greater than the removed root
        (That is why if we see a smaller element in step a), we 
        return false)
     c) push pre[i] to stack (All elements in stack are in decreasing
        order)
```

I am unable to understand the above algo, since I am not sure what is an empty stack (probably an empty array?), `INT_MIN`?

If empty stack as an empty array, then what does this statement mean

```
Keep removing elements from stack while pre[i] is greater
        then stack top. Make the last removed item as new root (to
        be compared next).
```

In short, I was able to formulate algo, There are algo's written in other languages but I only know how to code in Javascript.

Can you please help me by making the algo for the above code more readable?

Comment: Yes, you'd use an array (`[]`) for a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)), and `INT_MIN` is Java's smallest integer number, in JS you'd go for [`-Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY)

Comment: Did you have a look at the Python implementation? Python is usually much easier to understand than Java, and more precise than pseudocode.

Comment: @Bergi If the value is going to `-infinity` then isn't it obvious that nothing is going to be smaller than it? then why are we doing `If pre[i] is smaller than current root`

Comment: Exactly that's the purpose. It's an initial value known to be smaller than everything else, so that it will never be considered. (They could've chosen 0 as well given all the arguments are positive). We still do the comparison because the `root` variable changes during the algorithm. It's just easier than special-casing the first iteration of the loop, effectively duplicating it, only to initialise `root` with the first "valid" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answering your questions:

1. By `INT_MIN` authors meant the smallest integer (number) possible so that any other number will be greater than `INT_MIN`. For Javascript you can take `-Infinity`, it will be lesser than any other number for comparison purposes. You can not perform mathematical operations on `-Infinity`, but it is not needed in this case
2. Stack is a data structure (like special case of array) that lets you add elements to stack on top of each other and pop them from stack, returning latest added element. If you want to have stack in JS, you can either 1. create a wrapper on array, add `.push`, `.pop`, `.peek` methods or 2. just use array and treat it like a stack. It is easier to do the latter in this case
3. `If empty stack as an empty array, then what does this statement mean?` it is empty at first but as you go through the example you will see some items are still added to the stack, and there is a check for stack not being empty when you get to this statement

.

```
const canRepresentBST = (pre) => {
  const stack = []
  let root = -Infinity

  for (let i = 0; i < pre.length; i++) {
    if (pre[i] < root) {
      return false
    }
    while (stack.length && stack[stack.length - 1] < pre[i]) {
      root = stack.pop()
    }
    stack.push(pre[i])
  }
  return true
}

const pre1 = [40,30,35,80,100]
console.log(canRepresentBST(pre1))
const pre2 = [40,30,35,20,80,100]
console.log(canRepresentBST(pre2))
```

the point of this algo is to figure out whether or not given array of numbers (`pre`) is a valid [preorder traversal of binary search tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/)

Comment: Hey Max, Thanks for such an amazing answer. I was able to understand what you did in the code but why you did still remains unclear. Like what is the test to determine pre-order traversal.

Comment: This should answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285266/10433835

Answer (score 1):

This should be it. I took the java code from your example and transformed it into js.

```
const canRepresentBST = (pre) => {
  let root = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
  let s =  []
  for (let i = 0; i < pre.length; i++) { 
    if (pre[i] < root) { 
      return false 
    } 
    while (s.length > 0 && s[s.length-1] < pre[i]) { 
      root = s.pop()  
    } 
    s.push(pre[i]) 
  } 
  return true 
} 

let pre1 = [40, 30, 35, 80, 100]
let pre2 = [40, 30, 35, 20, 80, 100]
console.log(canRepresentBST(pre1) ? 'true' : 'false')
console.log(canRepresentBST(pre2) ? 'true' : 'false')
```